# Firefox - custom page in a new tab, focus on the page

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

When I open a new tab in Firefox, I would like it to display a custom page instead of the Firefox default. It should then focus the page itself, not the address bar.

The `browser.newtab.url` preference is no longer an option, but there are several extensions that allow using a homepage or a custom URL in a new tab.

I've tried:

- New Tab Override (browser.newtab.url replacement) 2.2
- New Tab Homepage 0.5.0
- Classic Theme Restorer 1.4.5

The problem with all of these is that when I open a new tab and the page loads, the focus moves to the address bar. I need to focus the page instead.

In the past I have solved this issue with a "hacked" version of *New Tab Homepage* from [this thread](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/791190) on Mozilla support forum, but I can't do that anymore since all extensions are required to be verified by Mozilla now.

Is there a way to use a custom "new tab" page *and* have it focused when a new tab is opened in Firefox?

**EDIT**: Question is about Firefox 43.

Comment: It might be more complicated than what you're looking for but you could use Greasemonkey to make a script that runs javascript on your newtab page to set the focus on whatever element you want.

Comment: @MC10 Thanks, I've done it with Greasemonkey with a simple `window.focus();`, which was sufficient for my purposes.

Comment: Sounds great! You could add that as an answer below with more details, in case anyone else wants to know as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for this. After installing the extension I've created a new user script similar to this one:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        New tab focus
// @namespace   your_namespace
// @description Focuses a page in a new tab
// @include     *://yourhomepage.com
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

window.focus();
```

Just replace `your_namespace` and `*://yourhomepage.com` with the values you need. For more information on the `@include` rules see e.g. [GreaseSpot wiki](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Include_and_exclude_rules).

For displaying the desired page in the new tab I'm using [Classic Theme Restorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/). If you don't need the other features it provides, you can use a simpler extension like [New Tab Override](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-override/) or [New Tab Homepage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-homepage/).

**EDIT**: This is for Firefox 43.